# Why in typescript taps only work first tap

Tags: javascript, typescript, pug

My problem is when i click tap only first tap is working when i click another tap is show error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
```

This my code
https://codepen.io/rodkeaw-rk/pen/NWavQPY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your html you can see you've got multiple elements with an id of 'panals'

[image]

So when you call

```
let panals = document.getElementById('panals')
```

It will return the first element with an id of 'panals', regardless of which panel you click on. This will be the 'John' panel. So when you click on 'Anna' and try and do

```
panals.getElementsByClassName('Anna')[0]
```

it will return undefined because panals will always be the John panel.